# Use different controller in route attribute in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

is it possible to use the `[controller]` parameter to refer to a different controller in the route?  I have a controller that I would like to have change based on the route of another controller.

Example:

controller 1:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class Controller1:Controller{}
```

controller 2:

```
[Route("[controller1]/user/[controller]")]//how can I make this route refer to controller1?
public class Controller2:Controller{}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to get `[controller]` to bind to some other controller name. It always refers to the controller that the router already selected.

The `[controller]` template actually won't match **any** of the examples you have right now. It tries to match the pattern `<Name>Controller` where `<Name>` is the token in the route:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller { }
```

Will match the route `/test`. (There's more detail in the [Routing](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/routing.html) documentation.)

If you want to prefix your routes with arbitrary names, you can hardcode them:

```
[Route("other/user/[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller { }
```

This will match `/other/test`.

If you don't want to hardcode strings, I'd recommend using a constant:

```
public const string OtherRoute = "other";

[Route(OtherRoute + "/[controller]")]
public class TestController : Controller { }
```

This will also match `/other/test`.